# how to select data that have the same value with sql?

Tags: php, sql

I have a table with three columns, `id`, `name`, and `value`, as shown below.  I want to count the average where the `id` and `value` columns are the same, how can I do this?

```
+----+--------+-------+
| id |  name  | value |
+----+--------+-------+
| 2  | rahmat |   3   |
| 2  | olive  |   5   |
| 3  | sari   |   3   |
| 3  | ryan   |   2   |
| 1  | zaki   |   1   |
+----+--------+-------+
```

Comment: `count average which have same id of value` ... average of which column?

Comment: Please review the answers given below.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this query:

```
SELECT AVG(value)
FROM table
WHERE id = value
```

The output from the sample table you gave in your OP would be `1.5`, since `sari` and `zaki` are the only 2 users whose records have `id` and `value` columns which are equal.

Comment: column id & name is foreign key

Comment: @Rayyan, Use  inner join, for better answer post your query.

Answer (score 0):

according to your question yes you need to use

```
SELECT AVG(value)
FROM #table
WHERE id = value
```

I have created a sqlfiddle here
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/4105

from the nature of this question I feel you trying to calculate average of values of those rows having same ids. If that's the case I have created another fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/4110 where you need to use group by

```
select id, sum(value)/count(id) as average from #table group by id
```

Lemme know if it is something you are after or you need something else.

Comment: or try this on same fiddle as well if you meant to calculate average value for the same ids                                                                                   select id, sum(value)/count(id) as average from #table group by id

Comment: after i try like this '$sql="SELECT AVG(idJawaban) FROM hasiljwb WHERE idSoal = 12015199 ";
$hasil=mysql_query($sql);
echo $hasil; ' i get  error 'Resource id #5' .can you explain to me  why?

Comment: I can't understand what these column "idjawaban" and table "hasiljwb" etc are. where you first in your example mentioned about id and value columns ,,,, did you try on jsfiddle ?